# Git: How to pull or fetch only specific changes

Tags: git

I have two Rails apps.  One of them is a template of sorts.  The other one is cloned from this template.  The clone has many changes I don't want in the template, such as additional views and assets.  However, there are a few changes in the clone that I want to put into the template.

I thought `git fetch` was the way to do this, but I'm not sure how to selectively pull in only the changes that are relevant.

This is what I got with fetch after switching to a new branch.

```
unknown:App user$ git fetch the_clone master
remote: Counting objects: 629, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (398/398), done.
remote: Total 537 (delta 361), reused 197 (delta 125)
Receiving objects: 100% (537/537), 3.62 MiB | 838 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (361/361), completed with 36 local objects.
From https://bitbucket.org/user/the_clone
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

But `git status` says:

```
# On branch the_changes
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

It's clear I'm not understanding how `fetch` works.  I don't want to `pull` because that will add all the changes.

Any advice on how to selectively add changes from the clone to the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the changes you want and the changes you don't want are in separate commits, you can use [git cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to pull individual commits.

When they aren't, you are better off copying individual files.